# How can I precompute the address of contract and use it for the deployment of a second contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, dao, factory, precompiled-contracts

When I deploy the dao with the `DaoFactory`, I also want a second second plugin installed, which relies on the `address` of the first plugin...

What do you recommend?

Should I deploy the second plugin separately after? or is there a way to precompute the `address` of the first plugin and pass it for the setup of the second plugin in the `DaoFactory` `createDAO` plugin settings?

Answer (score 0):

ℹ️ For the safety of any DAO, plugin dependencies should be avoided.

Nothing prevents one plugin from using another one, but having a plugin installed (i.e. permissions granted) which depends on another plugin (and version) also being installed (i.e. permissions granted) was intentionally avoided, because it would become a source of bricked DAOs.

In other words: cyclical dependencies, plugins that cannot be installed because another one depends on it, plugins that cannot be upgraded because of a dependency not being available, DAOs that manually revoke a permission which which another plugin depended on (i.e. no plugins being able to execute), etc.

- Plugins should be independent in terms of permissions
- The same permission should never be requested by two plugins
- It's OK if plugin A needs to use plugin B (as long as plugin B is always available)